# Sending to Azure Event Hub Error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm completely brand new to C#, Microsoft Azure, and basically everything. I'm trying to set up an Azure Event Hub that I can send data to. Right now I'm just following the tutorial that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send).

It builds just fine, but I receive the same exception every time. The message is the following: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487291/getting-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-from-az) but never answered.

Just to be sure I'm doing this right I'm attaching pictures with where I obtained the values for the Event Hub Connection String and the Hub Name.

Where I got the Event Hub Connection String from.

[image: Where I got the Event Hub Connection String from.]

This one is within the namespace - not the hub itself.

Where I got the Hub Name from.
[image: Where I got the Hub Name from.]

The code goes as follows:

```
private const string EventHubConnectionString = "<Connection String>";
private const string EventHubName = "eventhubtest";
```

Does the Hub Name have to be simply that or a path? Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own questions. First, I needed to change the connection string and make sure it contained the entity path within it. Then when establishing the hub client I did this:

```
eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(EventHubConnectionString);
```

HOWEVER, I was getting this exception specifically because of a firewall issue. I have to open ports (working on it right now) to allow outbound communication to the event hub. I believe these are ports 5671 and 5672.

Thank you to all that answered and @RayX who nailed it on the head.

Answer (score 4):

@Jamie Penzien, I had been stuck with this exact same error for days and my colleague asked me to change the following part and it worked.

```
var connectionStringBuilder = new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(EventHubConnectionString)
{
    EntityPath = EventHubName,
    TransportType = TransportType.AmqpWebSockets                
};
```

I am still trying to understand the reason, and it may have something to do with the company's firewall settings.

Comment: I did something similar. I made sure the connection string contained the entity path and then changed the setup of the eventhubclient to: `eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(<connection string>);`. Turns out my real issue was the firewall though. I have to open ports up for outbound comm so that way the messages can be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Eventhub name or Entity Path would be simply the name of EventHub found under an EventHub namespace.

You can use below code to create client:

```
EventHubClient eventHubClient;
var connectionStringBuilder = new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(EventHubConnectionString)
{
     EntityPath = EventHubName
};
eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
```

EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder can be found under **Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs** package.

Comment: I have done exactly all of that. I believe there must be an underlying issue that I don't know about as I followed the tutorial exactly, I'm pretty sure I have the correct strings for name/namespace, and I still receive the errors.